# Create flow diagram programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, charts, flowchart

I want to visualize components and connections of a [HVAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duct_(HVAC)) system with .NET/C#.
The diagrams will just include a few different components and their connections.
They do not have to comply to any formal standard and should look alike the diagrams attached. In addition the user should be able to select a single component/connection (so that I can display additional data).

Which **free** drawing/charting library would you use and why?

Thanks for your time.

[image: HVAC system]

[image: HVAC system]

Comment: see many samples at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julian,

Please check out GraphSharp: http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Small/open source C# library on Git renders to HTML5 (You can modify to render to for example WPF or Winform as well)

https://gridwizard.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/simple-c-library-to-render-graph-to-flowchart

Answer (score 1):

I would try to host VS studio designer in application , how you can host workflow designer for instance. Read about VS extensibilities

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get more free than System.Drawing...

Seriously, given your requirements I'm not sure you need a framework or library.  The most complex part of the system you describe is drawing the lines between components.  If that doesn't have to get fancy (automatic layout, detecting where the lines overlay other lines/boxes) then you can probably roll the whole thing custom.

Comment: He also needs to Select elements, and all in all I think some Component model would be appropriate here.

Comment: The entities (components/connection) that have to be visualized are not static. Also the number of entities can vary by a large quantity.
Therefore automatic layout is needed.